# Can diamond mods permanently delete answers?

Tags: support, moderators

This is a little embarrassing, but I accidentally [answered a question instead of commenting on an answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359/what-build-order-should-i-use-for-zerg-in-starcraft-2/4469) It's kind of weird looking at my answer every time I look at the question, so I'm wondering; can diamond mods view and permanently delete deleted questions? (Is this better suited for Meta SO?)

Comment: I saw that.....

Comment: Just pretend you didn't. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, diamonds cannot totally obliterate already-deleted answers. The only way for *any* content to be hard-deleted is for the devs to step in.

Comment: Anything @Grace says just automagically becomes reality, you're like Chuck Norris, Jon Skeet and Old Spice Man merged into one!

Comment: @Ivo Isaiah Mustafa, he's the Old Spice Guy, now look down, and look back at me, he's now Grace Note

Answer (score 2):

Well permanently, at least enough that anyone below 10k rep won't see it